# Difference between "sudo systemctl disable openvpn@client.service" and "sudo systemctl disable openvpn"

Tags: linux, openvpn

I have question about openVpn service. I want to **disable** the **openVpn service**, but I wonder what is the difference between "sudo systemctl disable openvpn@client.service" and "sudo systemctl disable openvpn"?

```
systemctl list-units | grep openvpn
```

and I get

```
openvpn.service                 loaded active exited    OpenVPN service        
openvpn@client.service          loaded active running   OpenVPN connection to client                                                 
system-openvpn.slice            loaded active active    system-openvpn.slice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openvpn.service` is mainly a historical leftover. Basically, it imitates `/etc/init.d/openvpn` for people who were used to older Debian versions having a single service that controls multiple VPN configurations in one shot, whereas the systemd approach is to have a separate "openvpn@foo.sevice" instance for each individual configuration.

In other words, the service doesn't start anything its own – its only purpose is to aggregate all `openvpn@...` instances. If you run `systemctl cat openvpn@.service` you'll see that it references openvpn.service, so `systemctl reload openvpn` would propagate the reload to all `openvpn@...` instances that you have running.

---

However, note that Debian's custom `openvpn@.service` is actually being replaced by the newer `openvpn-client@.service` and `openvpn-server@.service` units which come directly from OpenVPN itself. Those two service units are also multiple-instance, but they *don't* reference the "central" openvpn.service at all.